# Excel: Is there a way to create a pie chart that will reflect a percentage value from a single cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

Basically, I would like to have a graphical presentation of the data in addition to the numerical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but you could create the missing piece with a 1-minus formula then color the text to match your background.

```
Cell B4: =1-B3
```

[image]

Comment: That's it, thank you.